# Linear Regression confidence interval bounds

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, linear-model, descriptive-statistics

When performing a linear regression we first get a slope and intercept that is the best fit.

How do we compute the confidence interval for predicted values?

Here's an example:

```
y = 2x + 3
```

So for x equal to 2 we have y equal to 7.  If we also want to be able to say that we are 90% certain that the predicted value of 7 lies within the interval [X, Z], how do we calculate `X` and `Z`?

### Use Case

Some of the comments asked for the use case.  I'd like to show what the confidence interval for a predicted value in an application.  I'm using Apache Commons Math and I don't see a method that computes this in the Javadoc, so I'm guessing I'll have to code it myself.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/regression/SimpleRegression.html

Comment: Suppose we also want to predict the 90% confidence interval bounds on the predicted values. How do we combine the slope confidence interval and the intercept confidence interval?  It is vague. please restate your question

Comment: predicted values are based on specific assumptions. Your question does not adequately reflect what is the real statistical problem. State the background of your case.

Comment: @Ole, there are confidence intervals for estimates of slope and intercept coefficients, there are confidence intervals for the mean of y, and there are prediction intervals for new predicted values.  Their formulas, derivations, and examples can be found here: https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/295/ and https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/280/

Comment: Awesome - @AlexK.  The language I was looking for was prediction intervals for predicted values.  I'm using the Apache Commons Math linear regression utility and I need to compute prediction intervals.

Comment: I updated the question with the new terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the books I have seen this explained in details is Pagano's Principles of Biostatistics, in the chapter of "Simple Linear Regression."

The standard error of that particular predicted y, given a certain value for x, is:

$$\hat{se}(\hat{y}) = s_{y|x}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(x - \bar{x})^2}{\Sigma^n_{i=1}(x_i - \bar{x})^2}}$$

Comment: Any chance that the book has a simple example to go along with the formula?

Comment: It would be nice to see the answer show how to calculate the `X` and `Z` values referenced in the question.  I have to implement this in an application so if I have a solid example reference point it helps me guarantee application quality.

Comment: Here's a link containing the information for how to go about applying the standard error to get the confidence interval for predicted intervals:http://www.real-statistics.com/regression/confidence-and-prediction-intervals/