# How to compare predicted Y against a constant at different levels of a continuous X

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, likert, group-differences

I have a simple linear regression with a continuous $X$ (Likert scale, range 1 to 7) and a continuous $Y$ (people's prediction about an event, range 0 to 100). I want to see if the predicted $Y$ at one standard deviation above and below the mean of $X$ is significantly different from a constant value (say 50). How do I go about testing this? If $X$ were a binary variable, I would do a one-sample $t$-test of the mean of $Y$ within each level of $X$ and compare it against 50. But given $X$ is continuous, I would need to do something akin to a spotlight analysis.

This is what my plan is:

1. Recode $Y$ such that $Y'$ = $Y - 50$.
2. Run a regression with $Y'$ as the outcome variable at $\pm$ $1$ standard deviation of $X$.
3. The intercept should tell me whether at that specific point of $X$, the predicted $Y'$ is significantly different from $0$ (and hence, if $Y$ is significantly different from 50).

Does this sound correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your request correctly, I think the following may suffice.

1. Rescale the outcome to be $y^* = y - \bar{y} +50$.  This should force the intercept to 50.
2. Standardize the predictor by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation.
3. The resulting test of the coefficient for $x$ will test if a one standard deviation chance in $x$ is consistent with 0 (i.e. if the slope is really different than 0).  Rejection of this test should yield what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a 95% confidence interval for the predicted value of Y given any value of x and see if it contains the constant value. Also, you can make a test statistic using (predicted value - constant value)/{standard error}.
Formula for the s.e. is in any textbook on linear regression and can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/403695/linear-regression-confidence-interval-bounds).